# Accessing WordPress categories from outside

Tags: php, wordpress

So, I have a client that needs all the categories from their blog to be displayed on their homepage. The WordPress blog is in its own directory, `/blog`. I have tried the following code (taken from a tutorial, I changed the path to fit clients site):

```
<?php
    // Include WordPress 
    define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
    require('blog/wp-load.php');
    query_posts('showposts=1');
?>
```

But this code just redirects me to the install file of WordPress (it actually wrongly redirects me). It goes to `http://www.site.com/wp-admin/install.php` instead of `http://www.site.com/blog/wp-admin/install.php`.

Is there a better way than this method? I would pull in the categories from the database table, but I do not currently have access.

Thanks!

Comment: I guess you will find your solution here 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19500735/get-wordpress-child-category-from-specific-parent

Answer (score 1):

Client is using a weird CMS that I just had to understand better. Also, I included `wp-blog-header.php` instead.