# Get Wordpress child category from specific parent

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm building a small thumbnail gallery with posts from a category that has the ID 406.

Some of the posts are in multiple categories and I'm not sure how to grab the category name that is a child of 406. `$post_cat[0]->name;` returns a category, but I only need it to return children of 406.

```
$thumbnails = get_posts('posts_per_page=10&cat=406');

foreach ($thumbnails as $thumbnail) {

   $args = array(
     'type' => 'post',
     'child_of' => 0,
     'parent' => 406,
   );
   $categories = get_categories ( $args );

   foreach ( $categories as $category) {
      $cat_name = $category->name;
      $cat_slug = $category->slug;
   }

    echo $cat_name;
    echo $cat_slug;

 }
```

**EDIT*********

```
$thumbnails = get_posts('posts_per_page=10&cat=406');
foreach ($thumbnails as $thumbnail) {

  $post_cat = get_the_category( $thumbnail->ID );
  echo '<li><a class="side-thumb" href="' . get_permalink( $thumbnail->ID ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( $thumbnail->post_title ) . '">';

  if ( has_post_thumbnail($thumbnail->ID)) {

   echo get_the_post_thumbnail($thumbnail->ID, 'thumbnail');
   $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
   $art_image = ''.$upload_dir['basedir'].'/icons/'.$post_cat[0]->slug.'.png';

   if (file_exists($art_image)) {

     echo '<p class="artist-latest"><img src="http://site.com/wp-content/uploads/icons/'.$post_cat[0]->slug.'.png" alt="'.$post_cat[0]->slug.'"/>'.$post_cat[0]->name.'</p>';

    } else{
        echo '<p class="artist-latest">'.$post_cat[0]->name.'</p>';
    }

    } else {

    }
    echo '</a></li>';
   }
```

Comment: you are not making yourself clear here. you want all posts with category 406, even if it has other categories, or posts with 406 as only category or, posts which have category, which are child of cat 406?

Comment: I want all posts from cat 406, but some of the posts are in other categories as well. And I don't know how to retrieve the 406 category child.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So now I'm fetching a list of category and its child, then I fetch posts having parent category assigned to it, after I get posts array, I loop into it and get all the categories assigned to the post, If there are additional categories other than the required category and its child I skip the post, otherwise do whatever I want to do.

```
$category = get_category_by_slug( 'category-name' );

$args = array(
'type'                     => 'post',
'child_of'                 => $category->term_id,
'orderby'                  => 'name',
'order'                    => 'ASC',
'hide_empty'               => FALSE,
'hierarchical'             => 1,
'taxonomy'                 => 'category',
); 
$child_categories = get_categories($args );

$category_list = array();
$category_list[] = $category->term_id;

if ( !empty ( $child_categories ) ){
    foreach ( $child_categories as $child_category ){
        $category_list[] = $child_category->term_id;
    }
}

$posts_args = array(
'posts_per_page'   => 10,
'cat'  => $category->term_id,
'post_type'        => 'post',
'post_status'      => 'publish',
'suppress_filters' => true 
);

$posts = new WP_Query ( $posts_args );
if ( $posts->have_posts() ){

  while ( $posts->have_posts() ){
    $posts->the_post(); 
    $category_array = array();
    $post_categories = get_the_category ( get_the_ID() );
    if ( !empty ( $post_categories ) ){
       foreach ( $post_categories as $post_category ) {
          $category_array[] = $post_category->term_id;
        }
    }
    //Checks if post has an additional category
    $result = array_diff( $category_array,  $category_list   ); 

    if ( empty ( $result ) ) { ?>
       <li>
         <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="side-thumb" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"> dfdf<?php 
             if ( has_post_thumbnail() ){
                 echo get_the_post_thumbnail();
             } 
             //Put your default icon code here 
             ?>
         </a> 
        </li> <?php
     }
   }
  }
  wp_reset_postdata();
```

Above answer is as per your explanation, but I think what you want is, like you have a category Artists and there are subcategories each having a specific name, So for Artist gallery you want to display list of all the artists with their pictures.

Comment: thanks for the help. check my edit please. I don t think I m doing this right. Now it's showing the same category for all posts.

Comment: I don't know how to explain it any better. I think it's very clear. I have a parent category with an id 406. In this parent category there are child categories. Each child category has posts in it. Each of those posts are in the 406 child category as well as other categories. I want to retrieve those posts as well as the 406 child category. Not any other category.

Comment: Yes, but what if those posts are in another category too? I just edited my question. Maybe it will be clear if I show you my whole code. I need the category name and slug to display thumbnails.

Comment: Check if this works for you, I've excluded all other posts, only posts  which have category other than category 406, or one of its child category are processed

Answer (score 0):

I also needed to get list of child categories of selected parent category with url,

I found following code so useful

```
<?php

$categories = get_categories( array(
  'orderby' => 'name',
  'parent'  => 5
) );

foreach ( $categories as $category ) {

   printf( '<li><a  class="btn btn-light btn-light-custom mt-2" href="%1$s">%2$s</a></li>',
      esc_url( get_category_link( $category->term_id ) ),
      esc_html( $category->name )
  );
}

?>
```

Replace "5" with your selected parent category ID