# How To Get the children of the parent category by parent id in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

i try to get All child categories from my parent category 
like my parent category is news and child is news1 news 2 news 3

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19503347/4034148

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will [display all the child categories](http://www.upaae.com/display-child-categories-of-selected-parent-category-in-wordpress-category-page/) of selected parent category, tested and works in category.php template file...

```
$this_category = get_category($cat);
    //echo $this_category->cat_ID;
    $parent_term_id =$this_category->cat_ID; // term id of parent term

//$termchildren = get_terms('category',array('child_of' => $parent_id));
$taxonomies = array( 
    'taxonomy' => 'category'
);

$args = array(
   // 'parent'         => $parent_term_id,
     'child_of'      => $parent_term_id
); 

$terms = get_terms($taxonomies, $args);
if (sizeof($terms)>0)
{

echo ' <div class="categories">  ';     
echo '<p> Sub Categories of '. get_cat_name( $parent_term_id ) .'</p>';

foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

   $term_link = sprintf( '<div class="custom-cats"><a href="%1$s" alt="%2$s">%3$s</a></div>', esc_url( get_category_link( $term->term_id ) ),
        esc_attr( sprintf( 'View all posts in %s', 'textdomain' ), $term->name ),
        esc_html( $term->name ));

    echo sprintf( $term_link );
    }
echo '</div><!-- categories div end-->';
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

> Use following code for to get children category of parent category.

```
<?php

$parent_cat_arg = array('hide_empty' => false, 'parent' => 0 );
$parent_cat = get_terms('category',$parent_cat_arg);//category name

foreach ($parent_cat as $catVal) {

    echo '<h2>'.$catVal->name.'</h2>'; //Parent Category

    $child_arg = array( 'hide_empty' => false, 'parent' => $catVal->term_id );
    $child_cat = get_terms( 'category', $child_arg );

    echo '<ul>';
        foreach( $child_cat as $child_term ) {
            echo '<li>'.$child_term->name . '</li>'; //Child Category
        }
    echo '</ul>';

}
?>
```

Comment: How could I get this to work for my author archives?